# CheckBox event can not find javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, checkbox

I have a few controls designed to verify certain data before a user may do a soft delete on server data.

The error:

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.editdivision_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'show_confirm' and no extension method 'show_confirm' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.editdivision_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
Line 28:         <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDivisionName"  Width="250"  /></td>
Line 29:     </tr>
Line 30:     <tr><td><asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnCheckedChanged="show_confirm" /></td></tr>
Line 31:     <tr><td><asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="SaveClick" /></td></tr>
Line 32: </table>
```

The script:

```
<script type="text/jscript" >
function show_confirm() {
    PageMethods.VerifyDelete(CallSuccess, CallFailed);
}
function CallSuccess(res, destCtrl) {}
function CallFailed(res, destCtrl) {
    var r = confirm("There are active Campaigns in this Division!\nAre you sure you want to proceed?");
    if (r == true) {
        PageMethods.Save();
        //alert("Division and related Campaigns deleted.");
    }
}
</script>
```

I have been unable to determine why I am getting this runtime error. I am new to asp and javascript so I am sure it is something simple I missed, but I have been searching for 2 days on what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute `OnCheckedChanged` requires a server-side event handler, not a javascript function.

Try the `onchange` attribute which is the standard html attribute for the client-side event:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" onchange="show_confirm()" />
```

**Edit:**

It seems asp.net is generating a  element and applies the 'onchange' on the span and not the .

Found this post that deals with this problem: [Add client-side onchange handler to ASP.NET CheckBox control](http://www.michaelteper.com/archive/2009/03/03/add-client-side-onchange-handler-to-asp.net-checkbox-control.aspx)

Comment: I was trying that yesterday with some co-workers help. That assigns those to the span tag.

Comment: You mean that the 'onchange' attribute is set on the <span> that asp.net generates along with the checkbox ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I just got a new job and this is the first time I'm running page design.

Comment: Don't be sorry. ASP.net generates too much unnecessary html in my opinion and it's not easily controllable. Found this [post](http://www.michaelteper.com/archive/2009/03/03/add-client-side-onchange-handler-to-asp.net-checkbox-control.aspx) about this problem. Have a look.

Comment: That did not help :( While the attribute showed up in the input and not span, the method still did not get called.

Comment: In your question you missed the parenthesis `OnCheckedChanged="show_confirm"`. Sould be `show_confirm()` as it is a function call.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me, onchange and OnClientClick did not work, onclick did:

```
    <asp:CheckBox ID="EnabledCheckBox" runat="server" OnClick="showDiv(this.checked);"/>
<div id="ShowDiv">Show me now</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function showDiv(show) {
  if (show) {
    $('#ShowDiv').show("slow");
  } else {
    $('#ShowDiv').hide("slow");
  }
}
```